# Data science: How to find patterns and correlations in two datasets in python

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, correlation

I have two large datasets. Let's say few thousands rows for V dataset with 18 columns. I would need to find correlations between individual rows (e.g., row V125 is similar to row V569 across the 18 columns). But since it's large I don't know how to filter it after. Another problem is that I have B dataset (different information on my 18 columns) and I would like to find similar pattern between the two datasets (e.g., row V55 and row B985 are similar, V3 is present only if B45 is present, etc...). Is there a way to find out? I'm open to any solutions. PS: this is my first question so let me know if it needs to be edited or I'm not clear. Thank you for any help.

Comment: To find the correlation, convert the datasets into `pandas` dataframe and apply the `corr` function on it. That would give you the correlation of one column with another.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Row V125 is a value, perhaps you meant row 125. If two rows are the same, you can use the duplicate function for pandas or find from the home menu in excel.
For the second question, this can be done using bash or the windows terminal for large datasets, but the simplest would be to merge the two datasets. For datasets of few thousand rows, this is very quick. If you are using a pandas dataframe, you can then use the append function to merge them and find the duplicates.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an answer,
Considering the possibility that the answers may be useful together,
I pose the first part of the question as code,
After this point, it may be possible to solve it by making use of the first answer.

`

```
  import numpy as np
  from scipy import signal

  """
  I have two large datasets. 
  Let's say few thousands rows for V dataset with 18 columns. 
  """

  features = 18
  rows = 3000
  V = np.random.random(features * rows).reshape(rows, features)

  """I would need to find correlations between individual rows 
  (e.g., row V125 is similar to row V569 across the 18 columns). """

  # https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html
  Correlations = signal.correlate(V, V.copy(), mode='full', method='auto')
  """ As per docs: 
      Correlations variable above ,is An N-dimensional array containing a subset of the 
      discrete linear cross-correlation of in1 with in2."""
```

`

Ps: Using V and V.copy() may not be the solution you want.
I find it convenient to correlate a set with itself to arrive at conclusions.